# Fallback function - why revert?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

Just wrote and tested the following on http://remix.ethereum.org

Same happens on Ropsten network.

If I run without sending any value it works, but I can't deploy the Test contract if I put any value > 0 to send because it reverts, but why?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test
{
    uint public m_ReceivedWei;

    function()
        external payable
    {
        m_ReceivedWei += msg.value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `constructor`, so you can't fund the contract in the deploy because by default `constructor` is not `payable`. You can add the following line:

```
constructor() public payable {}
```

About [Constructor](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#fallback-function):

> A constructor is an optional function declared with the constructor
>   keyword which is executed upon contract creation, and where you can
>   run contract initialisation code.
>   [...]
>   If there is no constructor, the contract will assume the default
>   constructor, which is equivalent to constructor() public {}.

Fallback function works fine.

About [Fallback function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#fallback-function):

> A contract can have exactly one unnamed function. This function cannot
>   have arguments, cannot return anything and has to have external
>   visibility. It is executed on a call to the contract if none of the
>   other functions match the given function identifier (or if no data was
>   supplied at all).

Answer (score 2):

As you might know the constructor is executed once the smart contract is deployed thus when you deploy with value you need to define a payable constructor as follows:

```
    constructor() public {        
 m_ReceivedWei += msg.value;
 } .
```